# How to mimic export CSV functionality via Python code (where

Tags: python, request, automated-tests, testrail

When I use the export CSV functionality in testrail, I see that it does a POST request to the following API : /index.php?/plans/export_csv/:plan_id.

```
_token: <APIToken>
section_ids: 
section_include: 
columns: tests:id,cases:title,tests:assignedto_id,tests:original_case_id,tests:elapsed,cases:priority_id,tests:run_name,tests:tested_by,tests:tested_on
layout: results
separator_hint: 1
format: excel
```

Along with the following request headers.

```
authority: <Authority>
:method: POST
:path: /index.php?/plans/export_csv/:plan_id
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 320
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: notificationbar=12345; tr_session=<session_id>; tr_rememberme=<id>
origin: <Origin>
referer: <Referer>
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
```

Is there a way for me to mimic this via Python?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) package.

Requests is a library that helps you make HTTP1.1 requests.

Comment: I have used requests previously. Testrails is a tricky case, where regardless of how I send the form data, its not accepting it. Their Rest API interface doesnt support the same functionality. Hence trying to mimic what the UI does